# Find inverse matrix

Tags: java

I found function for calculate inverse matrix with jama java matrix class

```
public Matrix inverse()
Matrix inverse or pseudoinverse
Returns:
inverse(A) if A is square, pseudoinverse otherwise.
```

But i don't know how is this working or how to forward nxn matrix, so can someone explain me how it works with some simple example.
I found this function here http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html#inverse()

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the math behind it?

Comment: You can construct a *Matrix* object, and then call *inverse()* on it, which will return the inverse of the *Matrix* (if it is square) as a new *Matrix* object.

Comment: The docs looks pretty straight forward to me: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html